# Streambuilder render twice, the first time with initial data the second one with correct data, but the widget doesn't update

Tags: flutter, state, bloc

Hi I'm new with flutter and I have troubles with the state. I'm using Bloc to handle state, but when I try to set a state in my first view I can't show it in my second view.

In the second view, streambuilder shows initial value first and connection waiting, then get correct data and state change to active, but the widget doesn't update.

**First View**

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {


  Widget _divider() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: 30,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
              child: Divider(
                thickness: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController =TextEditingController();

  _updateEmail (String text) => userBloc.updateUser(text);


  Widget _emailPasswordWidget() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        EntryFields("Ingresa tu email", value:_emailController, onchanged: _updateEmail),
        EntryFields("Ingresa tu Password",value: _passwordController, isPassword: true),
      ],
    );
  }

  _goSignupScreen() async { return Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.signupRoute ); }
  _goHomeScreen() async { 
      _updateEmail(_emailController.text);
      return Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.homeRoute );
    }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      height: height,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              top: -height * .15,
              right: -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
              child: BezierContainer()),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: height* 0.2),
                  Center(child:  AppIconWidget(image: 'assets/images/logo.png', scale: 0.1)),
                  SizedBox(height: 50),
                  _emailPasswordWidget(),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  SubmitButton(title: 'Iniciar Sesión', onPressed: _goHomeScreen ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text('Olvidaste tu contraseña?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                  ),
                  _divider(),
                  FacebookSignInButton(onPressed: (){}),
                  GoogleSignInButton(onPressed: () {}),
                  SizedBox(height: height * .055),
                  AccountLabel(label: 'No tienes cuenta?', btnText: 'Registrate', onPressed: _goSignupScreen ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Positioned(top: 40, left: 0, child: BackBtn() ),
        ],
      ),
    ),);
  }
}
```

**Bloc**

```
class UserBloc {
  final _userRepository = UserRepository();
  final _userController = PublishSubject();;

  Observable get getUser => _userController.stream;
  

  updateUser(user) async {
      var currentUser = await _userRepository.updateCurrentUser(user);
    _userController.sink.add(currentUser);
    return null;
  }

  
   dispose() {
    _userController.close();
  }
}

final userBloc = UserBloc();
```

**Provider**

```
class UserProvider {

   Future updateCurrentUser(user) async{
     return currentUser = user;
   }
}
```

**Repository**

```
class UserRepository {
  final userProvider = UserProvider();

  Future updateCurrentUser(user) {
    return userProvider.updateCurrentUser(user);
    }
}
```

**Second View**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('title')),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        initialData: 'here!',
        stream: userBloc.getUser,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          print('...');
          print('${snapshot.data}');
          print('${snapshot.connectionState}');
          print('...');
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return Text('Select lot');
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Awaiting bids...');
            case ConnectionState.active:
              return Text('\$${snapshot.data}');
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return Text('\$${snapshot.data} (closed)');
          }
          return null; // unreachable
        },
      ),
    );
  
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing switch for connectionState, i think it is better if you use snapshot.hasData

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
   return Text('\$${snapshot.data}');
} else {
   return Text('Loading;);
}
```

Comment: I did it, but it's rendering only the initial data (here!), but when I see the logs, I see that the state is updating
I/flutter (21519): ...
I/flutter (21519): here!
I/flutter (21519): ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter (21519): ...
I/flutter (21519): ...
I/flutter (21519): 12345
I/flutter (21519): ConnectionState.active
I/flutter (21519): ...